# Tkinter browse button not working in CMD

Tags: python, tkinter

I was writing a little bit of code to rename a bunch of mp3 files (More an experiment than anything)

I finished the program and it worked flawlessly in IDLE but when I tried to run in from CMD (python C:/MusicRenamer) it gives the error

```
C:\Users\bradr>python C:/MusicRenamer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/MusicRenamer.py", line 9, in <module>
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = ( ("Music Files", "*.mp3"),("All Files", "*.*") ) )
NameError: name 'filedialog' is not defined
```

The Code

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
import mutagen.id3

root = Tk()
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename( filetypes = ( ("Music Files", "*.mp3"),("All Files", "*.*") ) )
print(root.filename)

#Find file and split artist from title
path, name = os.path.split(root.filename)
artist, titleExtend = name.split("- ")
Title, extension = os.path.splitext(titleExtend)
print("Title: ", Title)
print("Artist: ", artist)

#Rename files
filePath = root.filename

try:
    meta = EasyID3(filePath)
except mutagen.id3.ID3NoHeaderError:
    meta = mutagen.File(filePath, easy=true)
    meta.add_tags()
type(meta)

meta['title'] = Title
meta['artist'] = artist
meta['genre'] = "Space Funk"
meta.save(filePath, v1=2)
changed = EasyID3(root.filename)
os.rename(root.filename, path+"/"+titleExtend)
```

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks, Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is to assume the error message is telling you the truth, so all you need to do is answer the question "why isn't filedialog defined?".

When I do that, I see that your code isn't importing `filedialog`, so that's why you're getting the error "name 'filedialog' is not defined". IDLE probably imports it, which may explain why it worked in IDLE.

You're already importing `askopenfilename`, so you don't need to prefix it when calling it:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
...
root.filename = askopenfilename(...)
```